# What would happen in a tie in a Cricket World Cup final?

Tags: rules, cricket, tie-breaker, cricket-world-cup

Would the ICC take the T20 approach and take a super over? Or have one of those bowl-out things that used to be used as T20 tie-breakers?

Comment: They would do whatever it says in the tournament regulations. These can vary from one edition of the tournament to the next.

Comment: Any particular reason you decided to downvote my question? Also, do we know what these "regulations" are? I wouldn't think they would change them that much for such a specific situation, would you?

Comment: Yes, the ICC put the [playing conditions for every tournament on their website](https://www.icc-cricket.com/about/cricket/rules-and-regulations/playing-conditions). You can see (e.g.) what happens in the current World Cup Qualifier there.

Comment: Since it's a world cup, the most logical outcome would be to declare joint winners/co-champions. I could back my reasoning with the 2002 Finals ICC Champions Trophy between India and Sri Lanka.  The Final between India and Sri Lanka was washed out twice, to leave no result. I know the match was abandoned but in most cases when it's a tie, it's a tie and there will be no re-match, if they do it would be unfair. Another possibility would be a super over or a bowl-out when applied by ICC for the tournament.

Comment: I think it'll be a super over as per the playing conditions for the qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

For every WorldCup ICC will introduce a playing condition.
In 2015 Worldcup conducted by CA and NZC, they were

1. Quarter Final :
   If a quarter-final is tied, abandoned or if the match is a no result, then the team that finished in the higher position in the Pool stage shall proceed to the semi-finals.
2. Semi Final:
   If a semi-final is tied, abandoned or if the match is a no result, then the team that finished in the higher position in the Pool stage shall proceed to the final.
3. Final:
   If the Final is tied, abandoned or if the match is a no result, then the teams will be declared joint winners